# Magento RWD Theme: How to move related products to a new tab?

Tags: magento-1.9, rwd-theme, related-products

I am fairly new to developing in Magento, and currently on a local server developing a custom theme. Now, what I want is to move the related products from it's current default location, to residing in a seperate tab. From research I believe that a local.xml is required, and have made one. What code do I need to place within here ?

This image depicts it's current location and I want it to be residing within a new tab say next the reviews tab.
[image: current situation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just  add below ***layout code*** at ***catalog.xml or local.xml*** at `your app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout`:

```
 <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.info">
             <block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related.new" as="related_products_new" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml" after="additional">
                <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Related Products</value></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
```

Comment: I have inserted the code and it is showing. It is not staying within the tab but guess I should be able to edit this with css.